# Creating Matrix from Two Arrays using Minimum of both

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, minimum

Suppose I have the following (in python 3.7)

```
x = np.array([2,4,6])
y = np.array([3,5])
```

How can I obtain the output

```
np.array([[2, 2],
          [3, 4],
          [3, 5]])
```

Basically making use of the two arrays as the "axis" of my new matrix, and for each entry of the new matrix, take the min(row, col), without using any loops.

Comment: The expected output doesn't make much sense. Both arrays are of different sizes. which one will set the number of rows/cols?

Comment: I think .outer(x, y) will produce the array like the above, but with the entries being the multiplication of both. I'm looking for one that can take the minimum of both

Comment: `np.minimum(*np.meshgrid(y,x))`

Comment: You can use `outer` any ufunc like `minimum`: `np.minimum.outer(x,y)`

Comment: @Brenlla That will work also. You could add another answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `np.meshgrid` will expand both of these input variables into 2d arrays (returning a 2-element list); you can then use `np.minimum` to obtain element-by-element minima:

```
np.meshgrid(y,x)
```

returns:

```
[
  array([[3, 5],
         [3, 5],
         [3, 5]]),
  array([[2, 2],
         [4, 4],
         [6, 6]])
]
```

and:

```
np.minimum(*np.meshgrid(y,x))
```

returns:

```
array([[2, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [3, 5]])
```

(Using `*` here to expand the list into two separate arguments to `np.minimum`.)